# ScrollView/KeyboardAwareScrollView not working properly

Tags: iphone, react-native, scrollview

I'm having the following code:

```js
<SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
  <StatusBar />
  <KeyboardAwareScrollView keyboardShouldPersistTaps='handled' contentContainerStyle={styles.keyboardAwareScrollView}>
      <ScrollView ref={scrollViewRef} onContentSizeChange={() => scrollViewRef.current.scrollToEnd({ animated: true })} keyboardShouldPersistTaps='handled'>
        {steps.map(item => { return (<SingleAlgorithmStep key={item["Question"]} step={item} stepsDone={steps} clickedButtons={clickedButtons} algorithmJson={currentAlgorithmJson} actualizeSteps={(item) => updateSteps(item)} actualizeButtons={(item) => updateClickedButton(item)} />) })}
      </ScrollView>
  </KeyboardAwareScrollView>
</SafeAreaView>
```

with these styles:

```css
container: {
  flex: 1,
  flexDirection: 'column',
  backgroundColor: '#fff',
  alignItems: 'center',
  padding: 10
},
keyboardAwareScrollView: {
  flex: 1
},
```

Sometimes the `SingleAlgorithmStep` contains just buttons sometimes it contains a textinput. If runnig the app on android, everything works fine. But when i'm running it on ios and i get a text input, the scrollview does not scrolling completly down. I have to close the keyboard and reopen it oder manually scroll down. How can I fix this?